# What is the reasoning for writing files in chunks in Python?

Tags: python

I have 2 code snippets, one of which writes a file directly, and another writes a file in chunks:

```py
import requests

res = requests.get(someurl)
myFile = open(filepath, 'wb')

myFile.write(res.content)
myFile.close()
```

and the following, (which was presented as the recommended way)

```py
import requests

res = requests.get(someurl)
myFile = open(filepath, 'wb')

for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
    myFile.write(chunk)

myFile.close()
```

I experimented with different content lengths, and since they deliver exactly the same result, I was wondering what would be the reasoning for writing a file in chunks would be?

Comment: The most obvious reason would be `memory optimization`. Writing in chunks would be because the file is huge enough to store in memory at once. Hence, read it in chunks and process it one-by-one.

Comment: And the other might be that your input data stream comes in chunks or a stream, all tho from this use case that might not be the case. But that's one case where it might be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, sometimes a file is too large to be held in memory all at the same time (especially in the era of big data). Thus chunking.

You can find more details in the blog post [here](https://thepythonguru.com/python-how-to-read-and-write-files/) (disclaimer, not my blog)